# How Do I Prevent an Image from Shrinking When the Browser Zooms Out?

Tags: css

I have a banner image that looks just fine when the site is at 100% zoom in Chrome. However, if you zoom out (say to 60%), the banner shrinks and falls to the left. Is there a way to prevent this?

Here's the site under construction: http://dfars1.surge.sh/

If there is no way to prevent images from shrinking, is there another solution to maintain the appearance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image should scale normally even after setting zoom levels. Your issue lies with the fact that a `max-width: 2000px` is declared on the banner (`.dfars-banner`), which causes it to not expand any larger after a certain point of zooming out. Remove that rule and it should work.